# How to write an equation in two lines with a single equation number?

Tags: equations

I am trying to write an equation in two lines sharing a single equation number, as shown in the figure.

[image]

I tried this code, but it doesn't work in two columns format:

```
\begin{equation}  
\begin{split}
AdditionandMultiplication(a, b_i) & = \sin(p \omega \omega_{4_i}) \\
& AdditionandMultiplication(a, {b}_i + 1) = \tanh(p \omega  \omega_{25_i}) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Use `ed` version such as `aligned` or `gathered` and wrap it with `equation`.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest not to put the number between the lines, without at the same time adding a right brace that keeps the lines together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to solve your formatting issue:

- alignment only on the `=` symbols
- alignment both along the left-hand edge and on the `=` symbols.

Both ways are addressed in the following example. The first way employs an `aligned` environment, and the second employs an `alignedat[2]` environment. Both environments are explained in depth in the user guide of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather', 'aligned', and 'alignedat' environments
%% macro for displaying variable names (vn):
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathtt{#1}} % or '\mathrm',  '\mathit' 

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}  
\begin{aligned}
\vn{AdditionandMultiplication}(a, b_i)        &= \sin(p\omega\omega_{4_i}) \\
\vn{AdditionandMultiplication}(a, {b}_i + 1)  &= \tanh(p\omega\omega_{25_i}) 
\end{aligned} \\[1\baselineskip]
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&\vn{AdditionandMultiplication}(a, b_i)       &&= \sin(p\omega\omega_{4_i}) \\
&\vn{AdditionandMultiplication}(a, {b}_i + 1) &&= \tanh(p\omega\omega_{25_i}) 
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone} %change it to your own documentclass
\usepackage{mathtools} % you need this package
\begin{document}
\minipage{5cm} % you don't need this line
% code between BEGIN and END are what you need!
% BEGIN
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E &\not= mc^2\\
pV &\not= n R T
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
% END
\endminipage % you don't need this line
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `standalone` and `minipage` are used here to produce the image, you might not need them.